# Is there extra-biblical evidence for the earth going dark at the Crucifixion?

Tags: gospel-of-matthew, crucifixion, extra-biblical

> From noon to three, the whole earth was dark. (Matt 27:45, MSG)
>
> Now from the sixth hour there was darkness over all the land unto the ninth hour. (Matt 27:45, KJV)

This is a bold claim that few would make if it did not indeed happen. Do we have any extra-biblical records of this event, such as from the Romans or the Jews?